# Using pandoc to convert html to rst strips the newlines from the pre block

Tags: restructuredtext, pandoc

For example, when I conver the following page: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings

```
s = 'hi'
print s[1]          ## i
print len(s)        ## 2
print s + ' there'  ## hi there
```

becomes

```
.. code:: prettyprint

      s = 'hi'  print s[1]          ## i  print len(s)        ## 2  print s + ' there'  ## hi there
```

This is because there is a tag on the pre block: `<pre class=prettyprint>`
How can I make pandoc to print out the codeblock with proper space? `--no-highlight` didn't do anything it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the source code in your link uses `<br>` tags rather than newline characters. Pandoc should probably interpret `<br>` tags inside `<pre>` tags.

I have opened an issue on the pandoc issue tracker [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1620).